# How would the step definition be structured if I have to make a REST call and compare the response values to UI?

Tags: javascript, rest, protractor, cucumber

Here is a sample step definition where I want to eventually get the first and last name of a student from the UI and the GET API and compare them. At this moment, I am just trying to print the GET response and then build the test case from there

But it doesn't make the service call and the cucumber shows the step as passed. I am sure my format for step definition is not correct. How can I write this in a diff manner. I referred to this article here :- https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/step_definitions.md

```
            Then(/^I check the student info against the service response$/, function(){
                var request = require('request');
                var options = {
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'https://examples.com/manager/01',
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'username',
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Accept-Language': 'en-us',
                        'userID': 'Ap123'
                    },
                    };

function callback(error, response){
                        console.log("inside callback");
                        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                            var info = JSON.parse(body);
                            console.log(response);
                            console.log(info);
                    }
                }

                //text from page object and call to GET Service
                return this.pages.prd2Page.getstudentInfo().then(text => {
                    console.log("text from the UI: " + text);
                    request(options, callback);
                });
            });
```

Comment: It might help if you added the Given and When to your question to get a bit of context. This step seems to be doing far too much, generally a Then should be a simple single assertion

Comment: I am just testing out things. The given and when is just to get to this page, make a service call, collect the first and last name from response and UI and compare them. Later, I will move the GET implementation to probably a different file or something

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make a successful GET call this way

```
Then(/^I check the manager info against the serice response$/, function () {
    //var request = require('request');
    var request = require('request-promise');
    var options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://examples.com/manager/01',
        strictSSL: false,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'username',
            'Accept': 'application/json',                
            'userID': 'Ap123'
        },

    };

    return request(options).then(repos => {
        console.log(repos);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log("Api call failed");
    });
});
```

I removed the UI steps. I have to put them back but the service was not being called because of the quirkiness of promises. I installed another npm module called "request-promise" to help me use the ".then" syntax to structure my step definition